# Filter functionality of Material UI Datagrid not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using Material UI Data Grid to show a table. By default, it's showing an additional filter for every column for sorting purposes. However, when I click on the filter, it's going behind my Bootstrap Modal. Is there a way to fix it?
Here's how it looks when I click on the ID filter (the three vertical dots).

[image]

Here's the code for the DataGrid which is inside my Modal. Removed the html inside header, title, etc which is irrelevant. The return statement looks like this:

```
  <Modal show={this.state.menu} dialogClassName="modal-width">
                <div class="modal-content modal inmodal" >
                    <Modal.Header >
                        <Modal.Title></Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body class="modal-body">
                       {HCPTable}
                    </Modal.Body>
```

And this is the HCP table variable inside the render which contains the Data Grid. I'm using a few if conditions to show it which aren't important so haven't included them.

```
   HCPTable = 
            <div class="row" style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}>
                    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            rows={this.state.advancedSearchResults} columns={columns} pageSize={5}
                            onRowSelected = {(rowSelection) => {this.setState({selectedRow: rowSelection.data,
                                HCPSelected: new Array(String('[' + rowSelection.data.npi + "]" + rowSelection.data.first_name))
                            }, ()=> {
                                let HCPSelected = new Array(String('[' + rowSelection.data.npi + "]" + rowSelection.data.first_name))
                                console.log(HCPSelected);
                                console.log(typeof(HCPSelected));
                                console.log('state inside DataGrid: ',this.state);
                            })}}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want the filter dropdown to come in front instead of it going behind. I know it should be a small css change but don't know where to make it.

**Edit:**

So I found that changing the z-index in the console is enabling it to come in the front. I change the z-index in this class:

[image]

But how to access that class inside my application to make it a permanent change.

**Edit2:**

Here's a screenshot of what I want to change:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply styles to this classs through the customization points of a comoponent:

```js
const useStyles() = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        z-index: 500,
    }
}))

const yourComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <DataGrid
            ...
            classes={{
                root: classes.root
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

So if you want to override some other stuff, here is a list of available classes for the DataGrid component, which you can then target inside your root class:
https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#css

Example: You want your cells to be red

Then you would add the following code to your root object:

```js
const useStyles() = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        z-index: 500,
        '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
            color: 'red',
        },
    }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I used a different method. I have posted an answer for the same.

Comment: I've asked one more question related to styling of material UI Datagrid. You can check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002102/setting-z-index-of-material-ui-datagrid-filter

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a way by making these changes in the App.js file. Imported stylesprovider and then imported the materialStyles css file.

```
   import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
   import './materialStyles.css';

    class App extends Component {

    render() {
return (
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
  <div>
    <Layout />
  </div>
  </StylesProvider>
)
  }
  }
```

Materialstyless.css:

```
    .MuiDataGridMenu-root {
z-index: 3000
    }
```