# Setting z-index of Material UI DataGrid Filter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm currently trying to make use of the filter property of Material UI. This is how initially the UI looks like:

[image]

On clicking the filter button, I get this:

[image]

However, nothing is happening when I click on the columns, operators or value button. I think those fields aren't working because their z-index values might be wrong. Does anyone know the classnames for those fields so that I can set the z-index value accordingly. I know how to override CSS classes of Material UI. This is how I did it:

```
    import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import './materialStyles.css';

   class App extends Component {

render() {
return (
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <div>
      <Layout />
    </div>
  </StylesProvider>
)
```

And inside materialStyles.css I set the style:

```
  .MuiDataGridMenu-root {
z-index: 3000
}

.MuiDataGridPanel-root {
z-index: 3001;
 }
```

So basically, I just need the names of the classes that will help me to use those filters appropriately. Does anyone know the names of those classes for columns, operators and value (in the screenshot). Or is there another way through which I can make this work?

Although this isn't relevant but here is my DataGrid code for reference:

```
   HCPTable =
      <div class="row" style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}>
                    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }} >
                        <DataGrid 
                            rows={this.state.advancedSearchResults} columns={columns} pageSize={5}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
  
      }
    }
```

It is inside my return like this. As you can see I'm using React Bootstrap modal.

```
  <Modal show={this.state.menu} dialogClassName="modal-width">
     <div class="modal-content modal inmodal" >
       <Modal.Header> </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body class="modal-body">
           {HCPTable}
        </Modal.Body> 
            </div>
            </Modal>
```

Essentially, I just want to target the z-index of the classes of columns, operators and value in the screenshot.

**Edit:**

Have added a screenshot showing that I see the modal dialog in the elements table even though I haven't explicitly added it in the code.

[image]

Comment: Try this class: `MuiDataGridPanel-root`

Comment: Yes, I used this using which I'm able to see the filter. You can see in my code that I've already used that. But I'm still unable to make use of columns, operators and value. Do you know of a way?

Comment: This is due to your DataGrid being inside a Dialog. There's an issue about this on the official repository. This is a workaround for Material UI v4: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/844#issuecomment-802925610

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that repository. I'll see if referring to that code and making the appropriate changes helps. However, the code over there is different from my code so will have to see how I go about it.

Comment: I don't see DataGrid in the code that they have pasted. How can I apply the css classes that they are referring to? I'm not using the Dialog Component in my code either. It would really be helpful if you reference my code and suggest the changes that you are referring to. I'm still a newbie so it's still very unclear for me.

Comment: But the modal-dialog is automatically coming when I inspect that section using developer tools. I'll add that screenshot for your refence in the question.